# nginx as a docker upstream proxy with maps

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker

Trying to use docker to setup a bunch of apps behind a proxy using the nginx maps option for ease of configuration with a large number of backend applications.

The trouble I'm running into is the container won't resolve the addresses that I've given it with links.

I've tried using dnsmasq but that was troublesome, and didn't give me a working resolution.

Any suggestions?
nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  map $hostname $destination {
    hostnames;
      default host1:81;
      host1.test.local host1:81;
      host2.test.local host2:82;
      host3.test.local host3:83;
   }
   server {
     location / {
       proxy_pass http://$destination/;
     }
   }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
webproxy:
  build: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  links:
    - "host1:host1"
    - "host2:host2"
    - "host3:host3"

host1:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "81:80"
  volumes:
    - host1/index.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

host2:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "82:80"
  volumes:
    - host2/index.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

host3:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "83:80"
  volumes:
    - host3/index.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

Error I constantly get:

```
webproxy_1 | 2015/07/14 16:44:11 [error] 5#0: *1 no resolver defined to resolve host1, client: 10.0.2.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "host2.test.local:8281"
webproxy_1 | 10.0.2.2 - - [14/Jul/2015:16:44:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 181 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0"
```

Comment: Hi @Mycah! Did you solve this problem? I have the same issue here...

Comment: Same problem, as soon as I use the map directive, I got a "no resolver defined" error... strange

Comment: I did find a work around, and this method of proxying works great.  I'll need to reference my notes and check my current configs but I'll post it here.